# After changing a symbol, how do I update a device with the new symbol?

Tags: eaglecad, library

I have a device in a custom eagle library, consisting of a symbol and a package.
In the editor, I've swapped two symbol pins.

How can I bring the new symbol into the device?
It does not seem to flow automatically.
I understand of course that at least two pins on the symbol to package mapping will need adjustment as well.

So far I've been able to delete the symbol and bring the new one in, but at the cost of having to reconnect all the pins.  There must be a better way, and hopefully you are about to share the secret.  Thanks.

Comment: Explain what you mean exactly by "swapping" two pins in the symbol? Did you move one pin to the other side of the other pin? Or did you change the names of the pins?

Comment: I changed the names of the pins. Back in the device editor, the pins were in the original positions.

Comment: Any reason you didn't simply move the two pins in the symbol?

Comment: Only due to confusion, trying Eagle for the first time.

Comment: Totally understandable. Under normal circumstances, the device will automatically be updated when you change the symbol. The exception is, as you've discovered, when you change something that conflicts with the device - such as changing the pin names after you've connected them to pads. But that's easily corrected as Oleg explained in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disconnect pins from the package one by one and then reconnect them. Press 'connect' on the device screen . Select connected device, then the pin/pad pair and press 'disconnect'. If you want to have a part in a package similar to one already present you can use 'copy from' dropdown on the same screen.

Can't quite understand the issue though. On freshly created parts I shuffle pins around a lot till the  schematic looks pretty; they just stay connected to the package unless I attempt to change name in which case I'd have to disconnect first.